# rendered game doesn't work properly

Tags: rendering, game-engine

I created a game in blender game and rendered it. About 10 renders worked as expected, but since then every time I am trying to render it by: "Save as blender game engine" it doesn't. I have a menu which works perfect, when I press play The scene is being displayed as expected- all the meshes and the materials. The problem is that when I shoot on a door and it suppose to get opened- nothing happens. I can move, but only that method doesn't work. In blender (where I press 'p') it works. I have no idea what I did that caused this to happen. I assume it relates to the render settings because everything works properly in blender but I really have no idea how a render setting can affect something in the game. "Automatically pack into .blend" is checked, and there is a script I'm sure to be working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest to ask something like that in a forum, such as blenderartists.org. This question is too broad and belongs to your specific game.

Comment: OMG thanks!! ;) i opened blenderartists.org searched for save as blender game engine, then found this http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?394370-White-screen-of-doom&highlight=save+as+blener+game+engine and run the game via cmd- I had an error, "import bpy" which cannot be imported. Now it works :)